# How to Pass argument to batch file from Excel Macros?

Tags: vba, excel, batch-file

From excel macros I'm trying to pass arguments to batch file. My approach is given below

In Excel Macros:

```
passArgument()
Dim var, path As String
Dim wsh As Object
var = "#"
Set wsh = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
path = "C:\batchFile" + "\" + "run.bat"
Shell(path + " " + var, vbNormalFocus)
```

And I want to retrieve this var in batch file foe that I have followed like:

```
set "n=%~1"
echo %n%
```

But it's displaying n itself instead of #. I am new to this kindly help me out, Thanks in advance

Comment: Fix the code you posted. Do you use the Shell command, or do you use WScrit? Do you add a space between the batch name and the argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 - You need a space between the batch file name and its parameters

2 - If there is spaces inside the path to the batch file, full path and file name needs to be quoted

3 - To execute a command using `WScript.Shell` instance, you must call its `Run` method. In your code `wsh.Run( ....` . If you are using the `Shell` method of VBA, then no need for `WScript.Shell`.

4 - You are using `strBatchName` that you have not declared nor initialized

5 - The sintax to retrieve the value of the first parameter in a batch file is `%1`, with no closing percent sign

6 - You are not setting the value of a variable called `n`. There is a space after it. This should be written as `set "n=%1"` or `set "n=%~1"` to remove quotes in the first parameter if present. The included quotes in this line just prevent problems with added spaces in line or special characters inside argument.

EDITED - Document the discussed configuration

In excel

```
Public Sub TestRun()

    Shell quote("d:\test.cmd") + " " + quote("&<>,;!!"), vbNormalFocus

End Sub

Public Function quote(Text As String) As String

    quote = Chr(34) + Text + Chr(34)

End Function
```

In batch file

```
@echo off

    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion
    set "n=%~1"

        setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
        echo(!n!
        endlocal

    endlocal

    pause
```

[image: Shows the discussed configuration]

Comment: I tried your approach somehow now its working but I think there is problem in passing the argument from macro. Kindly look into that

Comment: I have edited the batch file but there is problem with macros kindly look into that help out

Comment: `strBatchName = Chr(34) + "c:\somewhere\the file is\run.bat" + Chr(34)` (quoted path to batch file, initialized variable), `var = "#"`, `Shell( strBatchName + " " + var , vbNormalFocus )` (space between batch file and arguments) - Please, read numbered points in answer.

Comment: I have tried with above approach and also edited my question but it's not running the batch file i.e, run.bat...

Comment: What is inside `<path for batch file>`?

Comment: It contain path for batch file called run.bat... I have edited the question again you can see

Comment: `c:batchfile` is a relative path. Are you sure what the current directory in drive C is for your current excel process? Please, change to an absolute path to try.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake in editing the correct path:- C:\batchfile. And my excel file is at the same location.Now hope its clear to you...

Comment: @Samraan: Please see answer. This is a excel 2007 file, with the IDE open and the code of the excel file, code of the batch file and execution of batch file. This is almost the minimal code. If with something like this your code does not run, maybe it is a configuration problem.

Comment: Thanks for your kind response. I'm facing new issue with approach, from macro if I'm sending following character(, | and ;) to batch file from macro then it's not retrieving but other character like(# $ ~) are working. Can you please let me know what could be the possible reason for that.

Comment: @Samraan: Look at the sample for the sintax in batch file `set "var=%~1"`. This assigns the unquoted content of first parameter to the variable, handling special characters. And in the macro, each argument needs to be quoted and separated from next argument by a space. In sample code, it will be something like `parameter=Chr(34) + "This! is (the | data)" + Chr(34) + " " + Chr(34) + "second argument" + Chr(34)`

Comment: Thanks for your response, I want make clear that at a time I'm sending only one arguments and I'm using the same approach what you said but the problem is that it's not working for following special character like ,(Comma) |(Pipe) and ;(semi-colon) And working correct for # $ and ~ I can't understand why this happening... please help me out

Comment: @Samraan: See updated answer. I think your problem has nothing to do with parameter passing, but with variable handling in batch files.

Comment: As we can see I have handle the variable in batch file correctly can you please suggest some other approach

Comment: From the code in question, if you do `echo %n%` and `n` contains special characters, when execution reaches that line, it is readed, `%n%` replaced with it value and then the line is executed. If `%n%` contains special characters, it will fail. Using delayed expansion and `!n!` sintax can handle it. See the screenshot in the answer (this is what i updated today, maybe i've not explained it correctly)

Comment: MC ND I cant see the screenshot last time it was visible but now it's not visible. If I'm using echo !n! then it displaying !n!

Comment: @Samraan: i've included the code from the screenshot into the answer. Try. When special characters are involved batch files can be problematic. If you find that your problems are with variables in batch code, post a new question and we will try to help on it.

Comment: Ok! Its working.. If I want to use the value of n as variable for some processing like search for it's value in a file then how I can use it's value

Comment: @Samraan: It depends. Not all parts of the system have the same behaviour. As said, special characters are ... special. Try and if you find a problem, post a question with your needs / code.

Comment: Issue resolved now... And A big thanks for your immense support I have learnt a lot from your suggestions and approach