# How can to handle the error: Run-time error '53' File not found

Tags: excel, batch-file, error-handling, vba

It appears when I use the next code, when I try to start a batch file from excel.

```
Sub RunBatch()
    Call Shell(Environ$("COMSPEC") & " F:\Financial\Data\Reports\ExpensesYTD\Batch1.bat", vbNormalFocus)
End Sub
```

I have this error:

```
erorr: Run-time error '53' File not found
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: While the question was different, maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20371414/2861476) could help

Comment: The command looks ok to me. Is F: a network drive? Also Are you sure that the file exists?

Comment: thanks Nima, in my computer F is a local drive. and i copy the routh to the file, i already checked if the file exists visually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What result for both

```
dir /B "F:\Financial\Data\Reports\ExpensesYTD\Batch1.bat"
dir /B F:\Financial\Data\Reports\ExpensesYTD\Batch1.bat
```

As we do not know which file the `Run-time error '53'` error message refers to, make public the `Environ$("COMSPEC")` result e.g. by `MsgBox` and check output from `dir /B %COMSPEC%`.

And consider to change cmd calling with `/C` in the syntax as follows:

```
Call Shell(Environ$("COMSPEC") & " /C F:\Financial\Data\Reports\ExpensesYTD\Batch1.bat", vbNormalFocus)
'or even 
Call Shell("cmd /C F:\Financial\Data\Reports\ExpensesYTD\Batch1.bat", vbNormalFocus)
```

The `/C` argument ensures that the cmd window is automatically closed when the batch file finishes executing

Comment: thenks Josef, the file exists and when i click on it, it work. it does not work when i trying to run through the Excel.

Comment: Ok, you can check if the file exists visually and see the file and even click on it etc., but all that  does not matter. All that done from _Windows shell_ GUI (e.g. from explorer) nevertheless your code calls _cmd shell_. Ensure the file is visible in the _command line_ window. To do that, perform both `dir` commands advised from `cmd` window... Also try `dir %comspec%` likewise.

Comment: thenks a lot Josef,the second line that you are bidding is works very well.  Call Shell("cmd /C F:\Financial\Data\Reports\ExpensesYTD\Batch1.bat", vbNormalFocus